# Why does $ not partially match on summaries of linear models?

Tags: r, dollar-sign

Take `summary(lm(wt~mpg,data=mtcars))->a`. `a$r` returns `NULL`, suggesting that there were no variables names beginning with `r`. However, both `a$residuals` and `a$r.squared` give valid output, contradicting this premise. What is my misunderstanding of the `$` operator? I thought that it always partially matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a clue in `?pmatch` (which is referenced in `?$` in passing).

> nomatch: the value to be returned at non-matching **or multiply partially matching** positions.

In the case of `pmatch` it's `NA_integer_`, but in the case of `$` I guess it's NULL (I don't really want to go rooting around that deep in the R source code to confirm).

More specifically, the ["Indexing by vectors" section of the R language manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors) says

> `x$aa` will match `x$aabb` if `x` does not contain a component named "aa" and "aabb" is the only name which has prefix "aa".

It doesn't say explicitly that NULL is returned otherwise, but that's generally what you get when there is no match (e.g. `a$junk`).

At a more abstract level, it's hard to think of an unsurprising/principled/non-dangerous way to resolve the ambiguity when there are multiple partial matches: pick the first alphabetical one (which could be different depending on locale etc.)? Pick the one with the lowest numerical index?

Comment: The partial matching is already dangerous in indexing. It should be removed and not extended.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that partial matching should be 'improved'; I was suggesting that returning `NULL` is a sensible behaviour, as it's hard to think of a better alternative